# How to find one of the two elements using xpath, in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I am trying to find elements whoose xpath changes, so I have tried this.

```
for j in range(0,10):
    try:
       datentime4 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mytab"]/div[1]/div['+str(j)+']/div[2]')
       if(datentime4):
                    break
       except:
            continue
```

But along with the above xpath is also wanted to find

```
//*[@id="mytab"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/span
```

There can be a preference like first search for the above, if not found then for the other.
I have just started learning python. so, guys please support.
Using Python3, selenium on windows 10

Comment: You can use OR operator in the xpath - see https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_operators.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the union operator `|` to declare your 2 XPath expressions :

```
//*[@id="mytab"]/div[1]/div['+str(j)+']/div[2]|//*[@id="mytab"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/span
```

Output :

If the two expression match : the result of the first expression should be returned if you use `find_element`(not `find_elements`). If the first expression is the only one to match : the result of the  first expression. If the second expression is the only one to match : the result of the  second expression. If none of the 2 expressions match : no match.

Side note : for safety reasons, please use relative XPath expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Apply f-string `f'My name is =: {name}'  #name = <my name>`

```
datentime4 = browser.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="mytab"]/div[1]/div["{str(j)}"]/div[2]')
```

Comment: But my question is to find 2 xpath elements. the code runs well for each of the path, but on using ```or``` or ```and``` attributes, the other element doesn't locate.

Comment: https://devhints.io/xpath check the xpath cheat sheet..

Answer (score 0):

The action that you are trying to perform can be done using the union operator ( | ).
You can simply pass the xpaths to the condition using the union operator

For eg : `xpath1 | xpath2`

Whichever xpath responds to the element on the webpage can be returned.
Also if the element you are trying to extract have some text written over it, then you can use javascript function to extract that as well.

For eg : `//*[text()='text']`